# How to detect mouth location in android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

For detecting face I am reffering to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html#. I am able to find eye differece and midpoint .

I am tracking eye positions with the following code :

```
public void trackEyes( Bitmap picture_gray){
        int width = picture_gray.getWidth();
        int height = picture_gray.getHeight();

          // r e s i z e the Bitmap t o o b t ai n e y e s ROI.
          Bitmap eyes_Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (
          picture_gray , width , height, false ) ;
          // d e f i n i t i o n o f the c o l o r o f the p u p i l s .
          int pupilles_color = Color.rgb ( 15 , 15 , 15 ) ;

          Point eyes_left = new Point ( ) ;
          Point eyes_right = new Point ( ) ;

          // b e gi n ni n g o f the t r a i l o f the r e s i z e Bitmap .
          for( int i = 0 ; i < eyes_Bitmap.getHeight( ) ; i ++){
              for( int j = 0 ; j < eyes_Bitmap.getWidth( ) ; j ++){
                  // i f the p i x e l i s under the c o l o r o f the p u pil s ,
                  // t h a t means an eye is found .
                  if ( eyes_Bitmap.getPixel( j , i ) <  pupilles_color ){
                      // i f i t i s on the l e f t s i d e o f the Bitmap ,
                      // i t i s the l e f t eye .
                      if ( j < eyes_Bitmap.getWidth ( ) / 2 ) 
                      {
                          eyes_left.set ( j , i ) ;
                      }
                      // e l s e i t i s the r i g h t eye .
                      else if ( j > eyes_Bitmap.getWidth ( ) / 2 ) 
                      {
                          eyes_right.set(j ,i ) ;
                      }
                   }
                }
           }

          // c a l c u l a t i o n s t o have the p o s i t i o n o f the e y e s i n f u n c ti o n
          // o f the o r i g i n a l g r e y s c a l e Bitmap .
           eyes_right.set( eyes_right.x-(int)(  width *0.1)+width / 2 , 
                   eyes_right . y-(int) (height*0.25)+ height ) ;

           eyes_left.set( eyes_left.x-(int ) ( width *0.1)+ width / 2 ,
                     eyes_left.y-(int ) ( height*0.25)+ height ) ;
    }
```

Now I need to find locations of mouth . Can you help me to find locations of mouth ? Any advice is of great help . 
[image]